# How can I delete a line in file if the line matched the required PATH, in Perl?

Tags: perl

My target is to delete line in file only if PATH match the PATH in the file

For example, I need to delete all lines that have /etc/sysconfig PATH from /tmp/file file

```
 more /tmp/file

 /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-lo   file1
 /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-lo   file2
 /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-lo   file3
```

I write the following Perl code (the perl code integrated in my bash script) in order to delete lines that have "/etc/sysconfig"

```
   export FILE=/etc/sysconfig

   perl -i -pe 's/\Q$ENV{FILE}\E// '   /tmp/file
```

But I get the following after I run the perl code: (in place to get empty lines)

```
  /network-scripts/ifcfg-lo file1
  /network-scripts/ifcfg-lo file2
  /network-scripts/ifcfg-lo file3
```

first question:

How to change the perl syntax : perl -i -pe 's/\Q$ENV{FILE }\E// ' in order to delete line that matches the required PATH (/etc/sysconfig)?

second question:

The same as the first question but line will deleted only if PATH match the first field in the file

Example:

/tmp/file before perl edit:

```
   file1 /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-lo   
   /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-lo   file2
   /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-lo   file3
```

/tmp/file after perl edit:

```
   file1 /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-lo
```

Comment: Is there anything much wrong with "`grep -v "^$FILE" /tmp/file`"?  This looks for the value of $FILE at the beginning of a line and does not print lines that match.

Comment: the problem is that grep cant edit the source file in real time, it necessary to print the output to other file and then copy the second file to the first file
grep –v word file > sec_file ; cp sec_file file

Comment: think about if I need to delete more then 100 PATH'S in the file -:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perl is a fine way to do it.  Use the -n switch, not -p.

```
perl -i -l -n -e'print unless /\Q$ENV{FILE}/' filename
```

Comment: nice , Andy if I want to check if PATH match the first field in file what I need to change in the perl syntax?

Comment: It's not only the "first field" in the file.  It's finding $ENV{FILE}'s value anywhere on the line.  Also, the \Q turns off the special regex meaning of characters like `.` in $ENV{FILE}.

Comment: YES but I ask if it possible to match only the first field , if it true match only the first field then line will deleted (see my second question)

Comment: @jon: add a caret `^` before the `\Q`; or, if you want to allow spaces at the start of the line, add `^\s*` before the `\Q`.

Comment: what to say excellent answer in the right time , your solution is amazing

Comment: If you are truly looking at fields, where fields are whitespace separated, you can also look at the -a switch for Perl, which autosplits the input line into a global array @F.  See also my slides called "Field Guide To The Perl Command Line" at http://petdance.com/perl/

Answer (score 0):

`s/pattern/otherpattern/` won't delete entire lines; it will only alter substrings. You need to entirely change your program to delete entire lines.  In pseudocode, it would be:

```
while (read in a line)
{
    if (doesn't match)
    {
         write the line back out unaltered.
    }
}
```

It can still be rewritten as a oneliner though, with knowledge of how `continue` and `redo` work in loops: `perl -pe '$_ = <> and redo if /Q$ENV{FILE}\E/'`

Comment: Seems a bit complex.  Does it have any advantage over  @andy 's suggestion

Comment: @justintime: nope, andy's solution is better. (I was originally trying to pull a `}{` trick but then realized it wasn't necessary here.)

Answer (score 0):

```
mef@iwlappy:~$ cat /tmp/file

aaaa 
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-lofile1 
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-lofile2 
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-lofile3 
aaa 

mef@iwlappy:~$ perl -i -pe 's/$ENV{FILE}\E.*//' /tmp/file

mef@iwlappy:~$ cat /tmp/file 
aaaa
aaa
```

You can do a further regexp to remove empty lines with s/^$//

Answer (score 0):

If I were doing this from the command line, I probably wouldn't even use Perl. I'd just use a negated grep:

```
$ mv old.txt old.bak; grep -v $FILE old.bak > old.txt
```

Renaming the original file and writing to a new file with the old name is the same thing that perl's `-i` switch does for you.

If you want to match just the first column, then I might punt to perl so I don't have to use awk or cut. perl's `-a` switch splits the line on whitespace and puts the results in `@F`:

```
 $  perl -ai.bak -ne 'print if $F[0] !~ /^\Q$ENV{FILE}/' old.txt
```

When you think you have it right, you can remove the `.bak` training wheels that saves a copy of your original file. Or not. I tend to like the safety net.

See [perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html) for the details of command-line switches.